# How to insert a YouTube embed using PHP into MySQL and retrieve it again

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following:
Youtube embed code:

```
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/nqNp9TgnXHk" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

I have a table where I store the youtube "**nqNp9TgnXHk**" part of the embed code.

- `id` - type is integer,
- `tube_code` - type is varchar ("where I store the embed nqNp9TgnXHk")

Using PHP how do I `echo` the string:

```
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/.$tube_code. allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

...so that I can insert and retrieve it from the ḾySQL table?

Comment: Do you mean that the YouTube video ID is already stored in the database, and that you want to retrieve it? What is the SQL query that you are using to retrieve it?

Comment: Yes, I have already inserted the video ID in the table. I now need to know the syntax of how to echo it correctly in PHP so that I just insert the code as a variable in the full iframe code. For example when I call it in a loop in PHP.

Comment: What have you tried? There are literally **thousands of examples** on StackOverflow and the Internet on how to query a database using a SQL query with mysqli or PDO.

Comment: I know how to query a DB, but I  thinking along the line of using mysql_real_escape_string(), but am unsure if there is not a better way of storing a youtube embed code.

Comment: The better way is *not* to use `mysql_` functions at all. They're officially deprecated.

Comment: Check out the [alternatives to mysql functions](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp).  If you use PDO prepared statements to connect to your DB and run queries, you pretty much don't have to worry about sql injection, if that's what you're worried about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Yourtable Where id='xyz'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_object();

?>
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?=$row->tube_code?>" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

... where `xyz` is the id of the stored youtube id.

Comment: There is a doublequote missing, right after `$row->tube_code?>`

Comment: hey @reto , thanks for the hint, I corrected my answer